# Different factor levels in R

Tags: r, regression

I am running a model using `lm` in R to look at the effects of two independent factors. These independent factors are breeding group (`bgrp`: 2 levels with `bgrp1`=maternal lines; `bgrp2`=terminal lines) and sex (`psex`: 2 levels with `psex1`=males; `psex2`=females); and using number of total born (`tb`) as a linear covariate. I have around 600 records altogether.

The model is:

```
mybgrp <- lm(formula = prtemp ~ bgrp+psex+tb-1, data = apirt)  #removing the intercept
mybgrp

Call:
lm(formula = prtemp ~ bgrp + psex + tb - 1, data = apirt)

Coefficients:
   bgrp1     bgrp2     psex2        tb  
37.72592  37.98272   0.14467   0.01982

> summary(mybgrp)

Call:
lm(formula = prtemp ~ bgrp + psex + tb - 1, data = apirt)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-5.6877 -0.2454  0.0768  0.3916  1.6561 

Coefficients:
       Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
bgrp1 37.725922   0.135486 278.449  < 2e-16 ***
bgrp2 37.982716   0.129558 293.171  < 2e-16 ***
psex2  0.144669   0.055140   2.624  0.00891 ** 
tb     0.019818   0.009342   2.121  0.03429 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1 

Residual standard error: 0.6888 on 621 degrees of freedom
  (5 observations deleted due to missingness)
Multiple R-squared: 0.9997,     Adjusted R-squared: 0.9997 
F-statistic: 4.788e+05 on 4 and 621 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

Now, up to this stage I could see the values of the two levels of the `bgrp` (`bgrp2=37.7`; `bgrp2=38`), but not too certain how to use the value of `psex2` (0.144669) or any other values in the table of coefficients to calculate the values of `psex1` and `psex2`.

After asking around, I changed the order of the independent from the first model to this the one below, hoping that it would give me the values of `psex1` and `psex2`:

```
mypsex <- lm(formula = prtemp ~ psex+bgrp+tb-1, data = apirt)
mypsex
Call:
lm(formula = prtemp ~ psex + bgrp + tb - 1, data = apirt)

Coefficients:
   psex1     psex2     bgrp2        tb  
37.72592  37.87059   0.25679   0.01982 

> summary(mypsex)

Call:
lm(formula = prtemp ~ psex + bgrp + tb - 1, data = apirt)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-5.6877 -0.2454  0.0768  0.3916  1.6561 

Coefficients:
       Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
psex1 37.725922   0.135486 278.449  < 2e-16 ***
psex2 37.870591   0.135908 278.649  < 2e-16 ***
bgrp2  0.256794   0.066167   3.881 0.000115 ***
tb     0.019818   0.009342   2.121 0.034287 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1 

Residual standard error: 0.6888 on 621 degrees of freedom
  (5 observations deleted due to missingness)
Multiple R-squared: 0.9997,     Adjusted R-squared: 0.9997 
F-statistic: 4.788e+05 on 4 and 621 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

As at now, I realise that `psex1` has the same coefficient value as `bgrp1`.

**My questions are**:

1. Am I doing the right thing (in terms of the package and models
   used)?
2. Am I interpreting the output correctly?
3. Is there a correct way of obtaining the values of these factor levels in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i) Yes, you are doing right.
ii) the coefficient for the missing level is simply **0**.
iii) because you don't have intercept in your model (the -1 does this in your formula), one level becomes your base (psex1 in your first model and bgrp1 in your second model). If you allow intercept (remove -1 from your formula), you will see 2 levels 'missing'.